# Can I use "Your Answer " option until I get Access to Comment On Other's Question?

Tags: support, comments, answers

I can't able to comment when I wanted to ask or say something on others question or answer.This is because my account doesn't have enough ability to comment on others question . Can I use "Your Answer" to do that? Or Using "Your Answer" option to ask is considered as Inappropriate?

Can I open a new topic as a Question If I want to ask some thing about others Question or  topic ?

Comment: @user402, The first thing you should do is give yourself a username.  Using the default username makes it look like you will not be around very long.

Comment: *@user402:* Agreed with *@Chris_O*; how about giving yourself a username so we can start getting to know you?

Answer (score 3):

I would not use the "Answer" box if your reply is not really an answer. The creators of this site see the [comment feature as a privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51926/new-users-cant-ask-for-clarifications-except-as-answers/51939#51939), and you need to show a little experience with the system (via your reputation) before you get it. The focus is on the questions and the answers, and this is a easy way to keep spam lower.

If you have a possible answer to the question, but only in some constraints, state it that way in your answer: *"If this-and-this is the case, you can do that-and-that."* That would be a valid answer, and I think you can use the comments on that answer.

If you have a related question, you should create a new question, and refer to the first question via a link. Asking a secondary question via comments is never a good idea, since they don't have the same visibility as a real question.

The best thing to do is participate more, and you'll get that 50 rep in no time. If you want to understand why your rep is so low, you can watch [the graph](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/402?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top), or even better, [the audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubt. Today I have posted a question which is related to other question (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1453/unable-to-edit-the-content-using-seaweed-plugin) asked by  another user. I wanted to get confirmed as there is no wrong opening a new question :)

Comment: @user402: I see some of your questions are [Community Wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow), so you won't get a reputation bonus if someone likes your question. If your question is not subjective, I don't see a reason to make it Community Wiki. Good questions deserve a reward.

Comment: How can I revert my Questions from "community Wiki" mode to Normal Questions?

Comment: @user402: I don't think you can do that, and in some cases (many edits) the question automatically switches to community wiki. You can give a question (and it's rep points) to the community, but you can't take it back afterwards (because how should the rep be distributed, if multiple people worked on the post?).

Comment: Yeah ! You are right .